# Property of unbiased estimators

Tags: bias, unbiased-estimator, function, convex

If $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are both unbiased estimators of $\mu$, aka $E[f(x)]$ = $E[f(y)]$ = $\mu$, is it possible that $f((x+y)/2)$ is also an unbiased estimator of $\mu$?

We know $f((x+y)/2)$ would be unbiased if the function $f$ satisfies the linearity condition, so $f((x+y)/2) = (f(x) + f(y)) / 2$. But what if linearity condition doesn't hold? Could we think of an example?

Some context:
I am thinking about this in the context of the sigmoid function in a neural network. When ensembling two models, we can average the probabilities, e.g. $\frac{sigmoid(x) + sigmoid(y)}{2}$. If each probability is an unbiased estimation, the ensemble probability would also be unbiased. But if average in the log odds space, aka use $sigmoid(\frac{x + y}{2})$. Would it still be unbiased?

Comment: This question is difficult to interpret.  It would seem that both $x$ and $y$ must represent independent samples of the same size from some distribution having $\mu$ as an (unknown) parameter.  Suppose, then, that this family of distributions is Normal$(0,\mu^2)$ and $f$ is the usual estimator of $\mu^2:$ namely, the sample variance.  Since $(x+y)/2$ is equivalent to a sample of a Normal$(0,\mu^2/2)$ distribution, the expectation of $f((x+y)/2)$ must be $\mu^2/2 \ne \mu^2.$ I offer this in a comment only to indicate where the question could benefit from clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would still be unbiased *in general*. Recall the statement of Jensen's inequality:

$$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$$

(for convex $f$ -- equality when $f$ is linear. Flip the inequality to get the statement for the concave case). For your case, $\lambda = 1/2$ and $f = \sigma(\cdot)$, which is the sigmoid function. I agree with you that using the formulation in the RHS, we still have an unbiased estimator. However, your estimator would systematically *underestimate* your desired parameter for the convex portion of $\sigma(\cdot)$ (negative domain), while overestimating your desired parameter for the concave portion of $\sigma(\cdot)$ (positive domain).

To complete the argument for the convex portion of the function, we'd take the expectation over both sides, concluding
$$\underset{x, y}{\mathbb{E}}\left[\sigma\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\right] \leq \underset{x, y}{\mathbb{E}}\left[\frac{\sigma(x) + \sigma(y)}{2}\right]$$
with an analogous results for the concave portion.

(Note that this is a slightly different regime than the $\varphi(\mathbb{E}[X]) \leq \mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)]$ version of Jensen that you may have seen in probability theory.)

However, even if the estimator isn't unbiased for any arbitrary distribution over $x, y$, it might be unbiased for some distribution over $x, y$ -- note that $\geq$ sign (I haven't figured this part out).

Comment: Thank you! I like your analysis of the sigmoid function. I am also aware of the potential use of Jensen's inequality here. But maybe the question is can we think of some non-trivial examples (not like x=y) where the logit ensemble would actually be unbiased? Or a more difficult question: for any function f without the convexity assumption, can we construct arbitrary distributions for x, y s.t. E[f((x + y) / 2)] = E[f(x)/2 + f(y)/2]?